# Javascript string in array or a part

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript array with multiple values:

```
var filterClasses = ['col-sm-12', 'hidden-xs', 'hidden-sm', 'hidden-lg', 'hidden-md', 'active', 'btn-'];
```

I have a function that gets all css classes in the DOM. But i want to check if this class should be added to a new array or not. So i can use indexOf for this:

```
return filterClasses.indexOf('col-sm-12');
```

This returns a true, so this class should be ignored.

But now i have a class that is btn-primary. As you see in my array i have the `btn-` added in it. I want to exclude all classes that contains the word `btn-`. How can i achieve this?

Current function:

```
function setupShouldAddClass( cssClass, filterClasses )
{
    // If the cssClass exists in the filterClasses then false
    if ( filterClasses.indexOf(cssClass) > 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    filterClasses.forEach(function ( item )
    {
        if ( stringContains(item, cssClass) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return false;
}

function stringContains( needle, haystack )
{
    return (haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1);
}
```

Comment: `filterClasses.indexOf(cssClass) > 0` should be: `filterClasses.indexOf(cssClass) >= 0` since a value of -1 means that no item was found.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. But how do i fix the other issue?

Comment: why return `true` in a callback for forEach?

Comment: Are you looking for [the `.filter()` function?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: It was a try cause i didnt had a solution for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can solve your issue using *regular expressions* instead of using imperative code:

```js
var classBlackListRegExp = /(col-sm-12|hidden-xs|hidden-sm|hidden-lg|hidden-md|active|^btn-.+)/i;

var result = classBlackListRegExp.test("btn-whatever");

console.log(result);
```

Check the `^btn-.+` part. This matches *anything starting with `"btn-"`*.

I believe that your scenario is the ideal use case of regular expressions!

### OP concerns if class black list is very large

OP said:

> what im wondering is, that if i add more then 100 classes, how does
>   this handle the line breaks?

You can join the whole array of black-listed strings and create a `RegExp` object with it as follows:

```js
// I use a templated string and String.prototype.join
// to create a regular expression from a given array:
var classBlackListRegExp = new RegExp(`(${[
  'col-sm-12', 
  'hidden-xs', 
  'hidden-sm', 
  'hidden-lg', 
  'hidden-md', 
  'active', 
  '^btn-.+'
].join("|")})`, "i");

var result = classBlackListRegExp.test("btn-whatever");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your absolutely right, it is simple and easy, but what im wondering is, that if i add more then 100 classes, how does this handle the line breaks? :P

Comment: Let me answer this on my own answer :D

Comment: Take your time :)

Comment: @DonnyvanV Done :D

Comment: @DonnyvanV No problem, you're welcome :) I'm glad this worked for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128983/discussion-between-donny-van-v-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check against each value and return true if found.

```
function setupShouldAddClass(cssClass, filterClasses) {
    return filterClasses.indexOf(cssClass) !== -1 || filterClasses.some(function (item) {
        return stringContains(item, cssClass);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nina! This solved my issue! I've choosen the first on, its more readable :) Thanks a lot! (need to wait a minute to accept the answer as solution :) )

Comment: You could check both cases in the `some` callback, that will increase performance since you wouldn't be iterating over the array twice

Comment: How should i do it?

Comment: @DonnyvanV Take a look at my answer... it's even simpler ;P

Answer (score 1):

I would loop over them like this.

```
function setupShouldAddClass( cssClass, filterClasses )
{
    // If the cssClass exists in the filterClasses then false
    var ret = true;
    filterClasses.forEach(function(el) {
      if (cssClass.indexOf(el) >= 0) {
        ret = false;
      }
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have the jQuery tag

Comment: I use jQuery in my project, no problem. Let me give it a shot

Comment: Just use `Array.prototype.forEach()` same thing

Comment: This function workds, but what Nina has written is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

How about bringing the `cssClass` to what you needed to be compared to:

```
var transformedToMyNeedsCSS = "btn-primary".replace(/^(btn[-])(?:.*)/,"$1");
 // --> Output "bnt-"
```

And then you compare as you are doing it now:

```
if ( filterClasses.indexOf(transformedToMyNeedsCSS) > 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole host going wrong here. Let's deal with it step by step:

First

```
if ( filterClasses.indexOf(cssClass) > 0 )
```

That is incorrect because `indexOf` returns `-1` if the search term is not found. It returns `0` if it is the first item in the array. So you want `>= 0`.

Second, the `forEach` loop:

```
filterClasses.forEach(function ( item )
{
    if ( stringContains(item, cssClass) )
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This achieves nothing. As in, genuinely nothing. Because you are inside a new function (the callback to `forEach`) `return` only returns from the inner function. And the return value is then discarded. What this code actually does is loop all the way through the array and do nothing. What you actually want is a clever function called [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). This loops through the array and tests each element. If you return `true` on any of the elements, `some` returns `true`. Otherwise it returns `false`.

So your code could look like this:

```
return filterClasses.some(function(element) {
    return stringContains(item, cssClass);
}
```

Now we want to ignore all classes where they begin with `btn-`. I presume this means that you want to `return false` if the class begins with `btn-`.

```
if (cssClass.indexOf('btn-') === 0) {
    return false;
}
```

So your function now looks like:

```
function setupShouldAddClass( cssClass, filterClasses )
{
    if (cssClass.indexOf('btn-') === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // If the cssClass exists in the filterClasses then false
    if ( filterClasses.indexOf(cssClass) >= 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return filterClasses.some(function(element) {
        return stringContains(item, cssClass);
    });
}
```